# Edit Text Field in Appengine Datastore Viewer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone know how edit a field with type 'Text' in the appengine data store viewer in production?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in the Datastore Viewer in the Admin Console.

It can be done in the interactive console, with some code like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
my_object = db.get('my_object_key')
my_object.my_text_property = 'The text I want to set'
db.put(my_object)
```

You could also write a handler that does the same.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, editing a 'Text' field is not possible. Only a 'String' can be edited.